# how to write dynamic code to optimize my script in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code, i want to do the same for 3 different dataframes df1, df2, df3.
the column in df2 is **10_11** and in df3 IS **5_6**

```
df1_30_31 = pd.DataFrame(df1_30_31['30_31'])
df2_10_11 = pd.DataFrame(df2_10_11['10_11'])
df3_5_6 = pd.DataFrame(df3_5_6['5_6'])

df1_30_31['30_31'] = df1_30_31['30_31'].replace(np.nan, ' ', regex=True)
df1_30_31['new_'] = df1_30_31['30_31'].apply(lambda x: '-' if 'nan' in x else x)
def Ok_fun(df):
    if (df['new_'] =='T-S') or (df['new_'] =='B-S') or (df['new_'] =='B-M') or (df['new_'] =='M-L'):
        val = 'NOK'
    elif (df['new_']!= '-') & (df['new_']!= 'NOK'):
        val ='OK'
    else:
        val= 'NOO'
    return val
df1_30_31['new_'] = df1_30_31.apply(Ok_fun, axis=1)
df1_30_31['30_31'].replace(' ', np.nan, inplace=True)
df1_30_31.dropna(inplace=True)
Nbr_not_ok_30_31 = df1_30_31[df1_30_31["new_"]=='NOK']['new_'].count()
Nbr_ok_30_31 = df1_30_31[df1_30_31["new_"]=='OK']['OK_NOTOK'].count()
total_30_31= Nbr_not_ok_30_31+Nbr_ok_30_31
ratio_30_31 = (Nbr_not_ok_30_31/total_30_31)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function that takes df, column as input and returns the processed df.

```
def change_df(df, col):
    # ...
    df[col] = df[col].replace(np.nan, ' ', regex=True)
    # ...
    return df

df1 = change_df(df=df1, col='30_31')
df2 = change_df(df=df2, col='10_11')
df3 = change_df(df=df3, col='5_6')
```